# Запрос к Яндекс.Картам из IE11

Tags: yandex-maps-api

При обращении к https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_ru яндекс.карт из IE11 приходит такой статус: 302 Moved Temporarily. Локально IE11 работает нормально, а после выгрузки на сервер ломается.

В хроме работает отлично. В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Для пользователей IE8 - IE10 [подключается](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/dg/concepts/load-docpage/) версия `2.1.oldie`. IE11 эта логика не затрагивает и возвращается последняя стабильная версия.

Comment: Получается, что дело не в урле. Локально IE11 работает нормально, а после выгрузки на сервер ломается.

Comment: Есть какая то ошибка в консоли браузера?